# How to create the mobile safari search bar scroll effect?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview

Can some one say how I can bring the Safari Search bar Scroll effect. I guess the Search bars must be placed as the subview of UIWebViews. When I tried doing it, no controls are accepted by Web view as its subview. Please some one help.